# in kubuntu 20.10 qemu+kvm+ovmf uefi does not work

Tags: uefi, qemu

I have repeatedly all downloaded and reinstalled.

I have written:

/usr/bin/kvm -bios /usr/share/ovmf/OVFM.fd -m 5G -hda /dev/sdb

or

/usr/bin/kvm -bios /usr/share/ovmf/OVFM.fd -m 5G  -drive file=/dev/sdb,format=raw

And for tests here I changed /dev/sdb to sda, b, c, ..., h in order to use HDDs and USBs.

The result is: devices that can be bootet in Legacy BIOS are bootet and work.

But devices which need to be UEFI booted are not booted but instead I fall into the EFI shell.

In the EFI shell I can use

ls fs0:

an see the file NvVars.
Nothig more is in this shell possible, and it is by no way possible to to come out of qemu.

But the UEFI device, a HDD, is bootable in UEFI mode, if this is done not via qemu but via the RESET button.

Please, does someone know a solution to this problem?
Thanks
Anton_Wessel@t-online.de

===========

reporting new invstigations to this issue (16
07.2021 08:35).

I have totally new installed kubuntu 20.10 on my hdd, using a different USB live stick bought also from the same company, i.e.

Freies Open Source Unternehmen
Chris Unger
Tux-Onlineshop

but reveived 07.07.2021.